# ImportError: cannot import name 'memoize' when doing python3 manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have an issue with migration in Django using `python3 manage.py migrate` it shows me about `memoize`

I have installed `django-memoize` and included it on my `settings.py` but it still shows the error.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/adminsortable/admin.py", line 15, in <module>
    from django.shortcuts import render
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.core import urlresolvers
  File "/home/mycomputer/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import memoize, lazy
ImportError: cannot import name 'memoize'
```

It should have migrated after installation of memoize.

Comment: Did you install memoize into system packages or are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: How do I check if I have installed it on the system instead of a virtual environment?

Comment: run `pip list` and compare results with your virtual environment activated and deactivated. From your traceback it looks like your django is installed into the system packages.

Comment: In my `pip list` I have `django-memoize (2.2.0)` and `memoize (1.0.0)` I don't have a virutal environment set.

Comment: Which django version ?

Comment: I'm using django version 2.2.2

Comment: Might wanna double check your django installation, becasue it's trying to load "memoize" from "django.utils.functional" and they removed it in version 1.9 (unless I'm missing something. not a django expert)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the support I need to install some dependencies and re-install my python then after that I created a virtual environment and install dependencies.